# Find the values of $k$ for which $\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}$ is irrational for all $n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

> I would like to find the positive integers $k$ for which $\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}$ is irrational for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I was led to this question when I was making up an example for my class, and I suspect that this is only true for a few small values of $k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $k\ge3$ is a multiple of an odd number. Then there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k=(2a+1)b.$ For $n=a^2b,$
$$\sqrt{1+\dfrac{(2a+1)b}{a^2b}}=1+\dfrac{1}{a}\in\mathbb{Q}$$
Now we only need to consider powers of two. Suppose $k$ is a multiple of $8.$ Then there exist $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k=8a.$ For $n=a,$
$$\sqrt{1+\dfrac{8a}{a}}=3\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Then only we have remained the cases $$k=1,2,4$$ which can be treated individually.

Comment: Oh, this answer is *much* better than mine!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is it easy to verify that $k=1,2,4$ all satisfy this property?

Comment: Nice work to @Barry and Nilan.  It is pretty easy to show that  $k=1,2,4$ all work. For example, for $k=1$, you need to show that $(n+1)/n = p^2/q^2$ is not true when $p,q$ have no common factors. Successive perfect squares differ by odd numbers at least 3.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3):

If $k=2^r(2a+1)$ with $a\ge1$, then $\sqrt{1+{k\over n}}$ is rational when $n=2^ra^2$.  If $k=2^r$ with $r\ge4$, then $\sqrt{1+{k\over n}}$ is rational when $n=2^{r-4}9$.  That leaves only $k=1$, $2$, $4$, and $8$.  But $k=8$ is ruled out by $n=1$.  So $k=1$, $2$, and $4$ are the remaining possibilities.

**Added later**:  Reading Bumblebee's answer made me realize how unnecessary it was to treat $16$ different from $8$. I was mentally locked into using the Pythagorean triple $3^2+4^2=5^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it easy to verify that $k=1,2,4$ all satisfy this property?